# How to run an application in Windows 2008 before login?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Last week, I needed to set up a Windows 2008 server. It required Apache Web Server, and I installed WAMP. The thing is: I only used Linux for servers until now, and I'm stuck with this:

I installed WAMP, which contained Apache. Now, if the computer reboots for unexpected reasons, the WAMP server will not start automatically. I tried registering Apache as a service, and/or added it to startup, but this requires a user to be logged in, and of course none of the tricks found on Google worked for the automatic login.

How do you start an app in Windows 2008 without requiring the user to login?

Comment: You've already pursued the correct answer: Running the program as a service. What you need to diagnose is why running it as a service is still failing or not initiating prior to login.

Comment: The startup type of the services should be set to "automatic". If it is and it's still not starting up, there's something else going on.

Comment: It will most likely be a permissions issue - what user is the apache service set to run as, and what does it run as when you start it after login?

Comment: Thx ForceFlow, after I installed it as service I thought it will be executed without any other setting, but it was set to "Manual"

Answer (score 0):

Apache, installed from msi, register himself as service under correct credentials (Local System account)

Comment: No, don't make it LocalSystem, unless you want to let any vulnerability in Apache or whatever you're running under it to own your entire box